# How to easily delay Query insertion in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, delayed-job, rack

I have one method that needs to handle large number of requests. I'm using Rack for it.

What it does is that it receive parameters and it creates a delayed_job task:

```
def self.call(env)
   ...
   Delayed::Job.enqueue(....)
```

To optimize it further I thought it would be nice to make the line above happen in the Background (maybe caching it in memory to insert the Delayed job entry in DB a bit later and increase responsiveness of the Rack App).

Any easy way to delay queuing Delayed Job task to save few milliseconds?

Current Bench mark is 12ms / Request so even couple milliseconds will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use workling/starling instead of delayed_job, then you can use Memcached instead of the database.

https://github.com/purzelrakete/workling

https://github.com/starling/starling

Comment: Good idea I will consider it. One reason I use Delayed Job is that I deploy on Heroku who use it. If I use workling/starling I likely have to deploy on my own host